# I am using ASIHTTPREquest I am geeting some issue in MAc OSx xcode 3.1

Tags: asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest classes from uploading a image on sever using cocoa with a php, But i have reference all the classes that requires in  for ASIHTTpRequest,but i am still getting some error,I am newbie to cocoa so not able to understand what the issue please provide me idea for  all  these errors.

-SCDYNAMICSTORECopyProxies", refernec from 
[ASIHttpRequest configureProxies] in ASIHttpRequest.o

InflateInit2_", refernce from 
[ASIDataDecompressor setupStream] in ASIDATADecOmpressor.o

"-inflate", reference from
-[ASIDataDecompressor uncompressBytes:length:error] in ASIDataDecompressed.o

"-inflatedEnd", refernce from:
-[ASIDataCompressor setupStream] in  ASIDataDecopressed.o

"-deflateInit2-", refernced from:

-[ASIDataDecompressed  compressedBytes:length:error:shouldfinish:in ASIDataCompressor.o

"-deflateEnd", refernce from

-[ASIDataCompressor closeStream] in ASIDataCompressor.o
symbol(s) not found

collect2: id returned 1 exit status

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone I faced this problem, because i am using it in Xcode 3.1,if u use in 3.2.3 code then you able to solve this problem.What you need to do include CoreService and libz.dylib library in your framework then you able to solve this problem> have solved my problem.